# Send emails from Azure Databricks

Tags: email, databricks, azure-databricks, email-attachments, aws-databricks

I would like to send emails from Azure Databricks.
I try to do this: https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/kb/notebooks/send-email-aws.html

But when I execute this:
`send_email(from_addr, to_addrs, subject, html, attachments=attachments)`...

...this error appears:
**NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sending an email from with Databricks is quite easy using Amazon SES. In order to do this, you'll have to make sure that you have access and proper permissioning with the AWS SES service.

Comment: As the first line states, please set up the necessary access controls in SES and maybe you need to configure the boto file ? Not sure - but see if the link is applicable - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/control-user-access.html - https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the discussion in comments.

If you want, you can try sending mail from databricks using logic apps **as an alternative**.

First store your attachment as dataframe and save as a file in blob storage.

In input data of logic app post request pass the file name as well.

**Databricks code:**

```
import requests as req
import json

input_data = {"Fromaddress":"mail","Notebookname":"Nb1","Toaddress":"<To mail>","filepath":"attachment.csv"}

url = '<your logic app POST URL>'

resp = req.post(url, data=input_data)
print(resp.text)
```

[image]

In logic app use `When a HTTP request is received` and give Body like below as per the input data in databricks.

```
{
"properties": {
"$content": {
"type": "string"
},
"$content-type": {
"type": "string"
},
"$formdata": {
"items": {
"properties": {
"key": {
"type": "string"
},
"value": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"required": [
"key",
"value"
],
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
},
"type": "object"
}
```

[image]

Then I have used a compose to store the attachment file name.

```
triggerBody()?['$formdata'][3]['value']
```

Then use **Get blob content using path (V2)**. create connection and give the container name and for file name give the output of compose like below.

[image]

Then use send mail action and give `triggerBody()?['$formdata'][1]['value']` for **To address**. add attachment in new parameter and **for attachments content give the File Content from Blob** and **for attachment Name, you can give compose output**.

[image]

Execute the Code in databricks notebook and flow will succeed.

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]